Sightseeing 6 hours day tour of Kuala Lumpur city from KLIA?
We are Indian passport holders with valid USA and UK visas planning a trip to Japan, which has 16 hrs transit at KUL. Like Singapore, do they have a organized sightseeing group tour of selected attractions in KL?

Yes. But not arranged by the airport. You have to contact a third party travel agent.

Is it 6 or 16 hours?

Is it 6 hours out of a transit time of 16 hours?
